# CSS pseudo-class selector not working as expected

Tags: html, css

I've got the following scenario:

HTML

```css
.input {
  color: red;
}

.input:not(:disabled, :read-only):hover {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<input class="input" type="text" value="Hello">
<div class="input">Hello</div>
```

So the hover effect won't apply to the div element, but if I remove the `:read-only` pseudo-class part from the css, it will.

Why is this happening?

Comment: `.input:not(:disabled):hover, .input:not(:read-only):hover { ... }`

Comment: According to the docs, read only also applies to elements that can't be edited by users. Which a div without contenteditable can't be edited. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:read-only

Comment: @imvain while that is correct you miss the `:not()` selector here

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:read-only#styling_read-only_non-form_controls <-- that section on non form controls tells you why it is happening. *This selector doesn't just select <input>/<textarea> elements — it will select any element that cannot be edited by the user.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `:not()` selector you are using is applying an AND logic so both requirements need to be true. `:not(:disabled)` and `:not(:read-only)`. The div doesn't match the second one (only the input does) so the hover effect won't work.

If you make it editable it will be like the input

```css
.input {
  color: red;
}

.input:not(:disabled, :read-only):hover {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<input class="input" type="text" value="Hello">
<div class="input" contenteditable>Hello</div>
```

Comment: It's clear how it works now. Thank you

Comment: why would a person make it editable? Unless the OP wants it to be an editable element... :shrug:

Comment: Without making the div editable, it won't support `disabled` and `read-only`, not even wrapping it under another form control element, I think.

Comment: @epascarello I am explaining how the selector works, I never said you need to make the div editable. It's to demonstrate how it works and it actually helprf the OP to understand (based on their comment)

Comment: The fun part is making it contenteditable and setting readonly is another edge case. lol

Answer (score 2):

Because the `read-only` selector doesn't just select input elements, it will select any element that cannot be edited by the user. This includes that div element.

@TemaniAfif's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77113810/9107694) uses `contenteditable` to make the div editable to make it supports `read-only` and `disable` attributes. If you **don't** want to use it for some reason (e.g. Editable controlled by JQuery or other Frameworks), you can use classes instead:

```css
.input {
  color: red;
}

input.input:not(:disabled, :read-only):hover,
.input:not(input, .disabled, .read-only):hover {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<input class="input" type="text" value="input">
<input class="input" disabled type="text" value="disabled input">
<div class="input">div</div>
<div class="input disabled">disabled div</div>
<div class="input read-only">read-only div</div>
```

Comment: technical incorrect. The `:not()` selector is the issue here. My answer proves that it works without issues. You not trying to select with the `:read-only` selector but elements without that attribute.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:read-only

Comment: This is literally what the document said.

Comment: @tacoshy Your answer includes 2 rules... only one needs to apply for the style to be included. Remove the disabled rule and you will see that this answer is accurate.

Answer (score -1):

The `:not()` pseudo-selector does not take 2 delecrations the way you intend too. Simply use 2 complete selectors.

```css
.input {
  color: red;
}

.input:not(:disabled):hover,
.input:not(:read-only):hover {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<input class="input" type="text" value="Hello">
<div class="input">Hello</div>
```

Comment: MDN appears to disagree with you: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not

Comment: tpay attentiont to: *the way you intend too*

Comment: I would assume that the user doesn't want a hover state if an element is disabled, readonly, or both. This solution will add a hover state to read only elements that aren't disabled.

Comment: If that would be the case, you could simply add them one after another

Comment: @tacoshy this won't exclude the `readonly` input. Check this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-hbkkhn?file=index.html,styles.css) based on your answer.

Comment: @tacoshy You could, or you could add them in one `:not()`, like the asker did. It's the fact that `:read-only` is matching the `div` that's preventing the rule from applying.